# Update SP called from Azure with input table parameter

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm new in Azure and I've inherited a project with no documentation. I need to insert a new colum in some tables and I've modified every dataset in Azure but some SP are called from Azure in the pipeline with input table parameters and I don't know how to modify this SP to insert the new colum.

This is my code:

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLoad] @azure_input_table [dbo].[InputTable] READONLY
INSERT [dbo].[Table]
columns,
new_column
SELECT
columns,
new_column
FROM
@azure_input_table`

But I'm getting the following error:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spLoad, Line 74 [Batch Start Line 6]
Invalid column name 'new_column'.`

Beacuse I don't know how to refresh the input table parameter to modify mi SP through SSMS. I've modified all the physical tables but I don't know how to modify this SP with Azure input table parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a table-valued parameter.  Check out the user-defined table types.  [dbo].[InputTable] does not have the column.  You should just create a new user-defined table type to replace this one and adjust dependencies (like this stored procedure) to use the newly created type.